# registering javascript function using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following script registered on page load:

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "watermark", "function WaterMark(txtWaterMark, event,text) { if (txtWaterMark.value.length > 0 && event.type == 'mouseover') {txtWaterMark.style.color = '#c6c1c1'; if(txtWaterMark.value == text) {txtWaterMark.value = text;} } if (txtWaterMark.value.length > 0 && event.type == 'mouseout') {txtWaterMark.style.color = 'gray';if (txtWaterMark.value.length == 0){txtWaterMark.value = text;} } if (event.type == 'focus' ) {alert(txtWaterMark.value); if(txtWaterMark.value == text){txtWaterMark.value = '';} } }", true);
```

Can I create this function in aspx and register in cs ?

Comment: Why you want to register in cs ?

Comment: @Adil because controls are inside updatepanel. if i dont register them, i get function undefined error.

Comment: Can you put necessary html with update panel so that I can suggest you some solution, I think we can do it without Registering the way you are doing.

Comment: my html is like this:   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Width="165px" Text="Enter First Name." ForeColor="Gray" onmouseover="WaterMark(this, event,'Enter First Name.');" onmouseout="WaterMark(this, event,'Enter First Name.');" onfocus="WaterMark(this, event,'Enter First Name.');" ToolTip="Type your First Name." ValidationGroup="CheckoutConfirm"></asp:TextBox> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it like this

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "watermark", "<script>WaterMark('watermark',event,'text')</script>");



<script>
function WaterMark(txtWaterMark, event,text) { if (txtWaterMark.value.length > 0 && event.type == 'mouseover') {txtWaterMark.style.color = '#c6c1c1'; if(txtWaterMark.value == text) {txtWaterMark.value = text;} } if (txtWaterMark.value.length > 0 && event.type == 'mouseout') {txtWaterMark.style.color = 'gray';if (txtWaterMark.value.length == 0){txtWaterMark.value = text;} } if (event.type == 'focus' ) {alert(txtWaterMark.value); if(txtWaterMark.value == text){txtWaterMark.value = '';} } }
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you can write your script code in a external `js` file and register it within your `ScriptManager` control:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ss" >
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/yourscript.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

But in this case you don't need to, I just copied your code and it works, try registering it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WaterMark(txtWaterMark, event, text) {
        if (txtWaterMark.value.length > 0 && event.type == 'mouseover') {
            txtWaterMark.style.color = '#c6c1c1';
            if (txtWaterMark.value == text) {
                txtWaterMark.value = text;
            }
        }
        if (txtWaterMark.value.length > 0 && event.type == 'mouseout') { 
        txtWaterMark.style.color = 'gray'; if (txtWaterMark.value.length == 0) { txtWaterMark.value = text; } }if (event.type == 'focus') { alert(txtWaterMark.value); if (txtWaterMark.value == text) {txtWaterMark.value = ''; } } 
    }
</script>


    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ss" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox 
            ID="txtFirstName" 
            runat="server" 
            Width="165px" 
            Text="Enter First Name." 
            ForeColor="Gray" 
            onmouseover="WaterMark(this, event,'Enter First Name.');" 
            onmouseout="WaterMark(this, event,'Enter First Name.');" 
            onfocus="WaterMark(this, event,'Enter First Name.');" 
            ToolTip="Type your First Name." 
            ValidationGroup="CheckoutConfirm">
        </asp:TextBox> 
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the output I'm getting:

[image]